# use str_replace with backreference

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace, backreference

I want to replace many different things with many other different things in a forum post.
I have an Array with all things to be replaced:

```
$stuff = array("word", "sentence", "cat");
```

Actually i want to take the string to be replaced to create the string in which to change, so i need a backreference. With preg_replace i can use $1, but this isnt possible in str_replace. So what can i use instead of an backreference? I cannot use preg_replace because that are static Strings and i cannot match it with regex.

Thank you!

Comment: please read the whole description of http://php.net/str_replace

Comment: _"With preg_replace i can use $1"_ -- Do you mean `\1`? -- _"I cannot use preg_replace because that are static Strings and i cannot match it with regex"_ -- You can build dynamic regex... Can you provide an example of input and output strings?

Comment: @hakre I read, and i didnt found anything. What do you mean?

Comment: @elclanrs no $1 is possible too. Hm how would this regex look like? Yes i can: The strings have to change to: <span class="tooltip [string replaced]">[string replaced]</span>